# Telegra.ph text formatting

Tags: telegram

It is said that http://telegra.ph is an editor that is able to format a text via HTML tags or markdown. In online editor neither the first nor the second method is working. What am I doing wrong? How to format text?

Comment: Where did you see that statement?

Comment: At https:/telegram.org/blog/instant-view it says telegra.ph is "a publishing tool that lets you create richly formatted posts with photos and all sorts of embedded stuff." They don't say what I learned to be the case. The floating menu is not available on mobile. I guess I wasted the bounty, because I edited the answer myself. Also see https://telegra.ph/Markdown-10-01

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see [API document](https://telegra.ph/api), there support only limited tags.

You can select text on [Telegraph Editor](https://telegra.ph), you will see floating menu which contains formatting options.

I think you mistake Telegraph as [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options), which provides `Markdown` and `HTML` formatting options.